# UIImage+ImageEffects doesn't work on device

Tags: ios, uiimage, xcode5, modalviewcontroller

I have a modal view where I want to present the results of a calculation. In order to make it all iOS7 look, I want a tinted background with a popup view with blured background.

I managed to got that thing to work using the files "UIImage+ImageEffects .h/m" from apple.

This is the viewDidLoad of the modal view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    /* How it works

     self.image is a screenshot of the VC presenting the modal view

     1- we set the background as the screenshot of the previous viewControler
     2- we hide the popup view
     3- we set the background of the popup as a blured snapshot of its container view    (self.view)
     4- we unhide the popup view and set its radius
     5- we create a tinted version of the background image (what we got from the previous view controller
     6- we set the background of self.view to the tinted version


     */

    // ***  1  ***

    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.image];


     // ***  2  ***

    self.containerView.hidden=YES;


    // ***  3  ***

    UIImage *pepe=[self bluredImageFromView:self.containerView withBackground:self.view withBackgroundTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.75]];
    self.containerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:pepe];

    // ***  4  ***

    self.containerView.hidden=NO;
    self.containerView.layer.cornerRadius=4.5f;

    // ***  5  ***

    UIImage *tintedBackground =[self.image applyBlurWithRadius:0
                                                      tintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.85 green:0.85 blue:0.85 alpha:0.35]
                                          saturationDeltaFactor:1.8
                                                      maskImage:nil];
    // ***  6  ***

    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:tintedBackground];


}
```

it works very well on the simulators but when I tried onmy iPhone (4S), when the modal view is presented, I've got a black screen. No errors, no complaining from the console, no nothing.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

I add the code:

```
if (!self.image) NSLog (@"self.image is empty");
```

at the very beginning of viewDidLoad

It seems that on the simulator self.image is not nil whereas on the device it is. I've tried to instantiate self.image from **prepareForSegue** on the parent VC but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your `bluredImageFromView` is working, but there are security(sandbox) differences between the simulator and an actual iOS device (particularly with `resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:` and `drawViewHierarchyInRect:`) which might explain why it works (but then doesn't on a device.) 
Check out this [thread](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=8993&start=10) at raywenderlich.com where someone got advice from Apple Developer tech support. This example code is apparently from Apple.

```
- (IBAction)doBlurAndCrop:(id)sender {

UIImage *snapshotImage;

    /* draw the image of all the views below our view */
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.sourceImageView.bounds.size, NO, 0);
BOOL successfulDrawHierarchy = [self.sourceImageView drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.sourceImageView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
if ( successfulDrawHierarchy ) {
    snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
} else {
    NSLog(@"drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: failed - there's nothing to draw...");
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

if ( successfulDrawHierarchy ) {

        /* calculate the coordinates of the rectangle we're interested in within the returned image */
    CGRect cropRect = CGRectOffset(self.targetImageView.frame, - self.sourceImageView.frame.origin.x, - self.sourceImageView.frame.origin.y);

        /* draw the cropped section with a clipping region */
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size, YES, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, cropRect.size.width, cropRect.size.height));
    CGRect targetRectangeForCrop = CGRectMake(-cropRect.origin.x, -cropRect.origin.y, snapshotImage.size.width, snapshotImage.size.height);
    [snapshotImage drawInRect:targetRectangeForCrop];
    UIImage *croppedSnapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        /* apply a special effect to the resulting image and copy it into place on screen */
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.3];
    self.targetImageView.image = [croppedSnapshotImage applyBlurWithRadius:5 tintColor:tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:1.8 maskImage:nil];
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I was actually adaptic a snip code from Ray Wenderlicht's tutorial, exactly the one this thread you pointed out was about. I adapted my method with this code you provide and it now works like a charm. I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: You're welcome. I'd be curious to know if the `applyBlurWithRadius:tintColor:saturationDeltaFactor:maskImage:` works on an iPhone 4.

Comment: I can only tell you that with my 4s it works flawless. I will try it on my iPad 3 in a few days before I submit the App.